# .css and .js returns error 500 when called by HTML, but not when opened in new tab

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

No files that are requested by the HTML (i.e. `<link>` tag, or `<script src=...` tag) work. Every time they return error 500 regardless of the browser.

If I open the said file in a - I see the contents correctly. I can right click the URL when I do View Source to make sure there's no typo.

Refreshing the page does not add new lines to /var/log/apache2/error.log

Ubuntu 10.04 - 32bit

Example of HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import '/css/main.css';
a em, button em {font-style:normal; text-decoration:underline;}
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/floatbox/floatbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/floatbox/floatbox.js"></script>
```

---

Found some cause:
Issues with javascript were unrelated -- that was my fault entirely.
For .css I parse those files using PHP also. This was done by the following line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .css
```

I tried changing it to

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .css
```

But with no success -- if **either one** of the two lines above is present, then I get Error 500.

Comment: Define "open the said file in a new tab".  Did you open a tab, then type in the URL for the file in question?  Did you do something else?

Comment: That's exactly what I do

Comment: Are you sure that the browser requests the correct URL? What do you see in firebug or wireshark?

Comment: Seems like there is problem only when referrer is set. Maybe mod_rewrite problem?

Comment: can you please post your HTML HEADER?

Comment: I updated the OP with some HTML Petr I don't use mod_rewrite :-/. helle - what is HTML HEADER?

Comment: I think with html header should be the `head` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something that could have been solved by the community. The error 500 was triggered because I had called an xdebug function from a registered shutdown function but I did not have xdebug module loaded correctly.